# Compute days-until-next-event based on date diffs in dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, datetime

I have a pandas dataframe that I would like to calculate `days_until_next_event` for:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'message_count': [1, 3, 5, 6, 2, 8, 10, 2], 'event_date': ['2016-01-05', '2016-01-05', '2016-01-05', '2016-01-13', '2016-01-13', '2016-01-13', '2016-01-28', '2016-01-28'], 'message_date': ['2016-01-05', '2016-01-06', '2016-01-10', '2016-01-13', '2016-01-16', '2016-01-22', '2016-01-28', '2016-01-30']})

event_date  message_count   message_date
2016-01-05       1           2016-01-05
2016-01-05       3           2016-01-06
2016-01-05       5           2016-01-10
2016-01-13       6           2016-01-13
2016-01-13       2           2016-01-16
2016-01-13       8           2016-01-22
2016-01-28       10          2016-01-28
2016-01-28       2           2016-01-30
```

The expected dataframe would look like this:

```
days_until_next_event   event_date  message_count   message_date    
      0 days            2016-01-05       1           2016-01-05 
      7 days            2016-01-05       3           2016-01-06 
      3 days            2016-01-05       5           2016-01-10 
      0 days            2016-01-13       6           2016-01-13 
      12 days           2016-01-13       2           2016-01-16 
      6 days            2016-01-13       8           2016-01-22 
      0 days            2016-01-28      10           2016-01-28 
      NaT               2016-01-28       2           2016-01-30
```

Where `days_until_next_event` is the difference between the `message_date` and the next *new* `event_date`. If the two dates are the same, then it would have a value of 0. I'm able to get days since last event with:

```
df2['days_since_last_dte'] = [(message - event) for message, event in zip(df2['message_date'], df2['event_date'])]
```

but am having trouble adding the last piece of comparing that to the next "new" `event_date`

Comment: Please explain how dune = "7 days" for the record `event_date=2016-01-05, message_count=3, message_date=2016-01-06` ? Why was the next new message_date not 2016-01-10 (from line 3), thus "5 days"?

Comment: @smci Because dune is calculated off of the next *new* `event_date` not the `event_date` itself. In that case, for `event_date=2016-01-05, message_count=3, message_date=2016-01-06` it would be `2016-01-13` - `2016-01-06` = 7 days. For `message_date = 2016-01-10` it would be `2016-13-01` - `2016-01-10` = 3 days. All `message_dates` with `event_date` = `2016-01-05` would use `event_date` = `2016-01-13` in it's dune calculation since that is the next event. Hope this clarifies your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `bfill`:

```
df.event_date = pd.to_datetime(df.event_date)
df.message_date = pd.to_datetime(df.message_date)
```

Create a new column 'next_event_date'

```
df['next_event_date'] = df.loc[df.event_date != df.event_date.shift(1),'event_date']
```

Backfill next_event_date to lineup data:

```
df['next_event_date'] = df['next_event_date'].bfill()
```

Subtract next_event_date and message_date:

```
df['days_until_next_event'] = df['next_event_date'] - df['message_date']
print(df)
```

Output:

```
  event_date  message_count message_date next_event_date days_until_next_event
0 2016-01-05              1   2016-01-05      2016-01-05                0 days
1 2016-01-05              3   2016-01-06      2016-01-13                7 days
2 2016-01-05              5   2016-01-10      2016-01-13                3 days
3 2016-01-13              6   2016-01-13      2016-01-13                0 days
4 2016-01-13              2   2016-01-16      2016-01-28               12 days
5 2016-01-13              8   2016-01-22      2016-01-28                6 days
6 2016-01-28             10   2016-01-28      2016-01-28                0 days
7 2016-01-28              2   2016-01-30             NaT                   NaT
```

Comment: This is great, thanks! I was using `.bfill()` for something else and hadn't considered using it with `.shift()` for this purpose!

Answer (score 4):

IIUC (PS: assuming yout df is sorted, if not `sort_values` firstly)

```
df['New']=df.event_date.map(pd.Series(df.event_date.unique()[1:],index=df.event_date.unique()[:-1]))

df.loc[df.groupby('event_date').head(1).index,'DiffDays']=0

df
Out[1191]: 
   event_date  message_count message_date        New          DiffDays
0  2016-01-05              1   2016-01-05 2016-01-13                 0
1  2016-01-05              3   2016-01-06 2016-01-13   7 days 00:00:00
2  2016-01-05              5   2016-01-10 2016-01-13   3 days 00:00:00
3  2016-01-13              6   2016-01-13 2016-01-28                 0
4  2016-01-13              2   2016-01-16 2016-01-28  12 days 00:00:00
5  2016-01-13              8   2016-01-22 2016-01-28   6 days 00:00:00
6  2016-01-28             10   2016-01-28        NaT                 0
7  2016-01-28              2   2016-01-30        NaT               NaT
```